# IE8 - jQuery: position().left' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, position

Here's the line of code that is causing a problem. I've searched google for similar issues, and tried replacing 'x' and 'y' with '_x' and '_y' but still no beans

```
x = $(display).position().left + $(display).width() - 84,
```

And here is the rest of the function that pertains to this issue

```
      function displayLinks(img,row) {
            var num = $(img).attr('num'),
                display = $('img.gDisplay'),
                x = $(display).position().left + $(display).width() - 84,
                y = row == 0 ? op.height - 84 : - (rows - row - 1) * (op.height + op.margin) + op.height - 84;
            var more = $('<div class="hover-link rounded" id="more-' + num + '" />').css({
                left:x,
                top:y
            }).appendTo( $('ul#row-0') );
            ...
       }
```

Comment: It musn't be able to find img.gDisplay.  Is the class name definitely correct, and are you running the code after the document is ready?

Comment: It works fine on every browser except IE8, so in other words yes

Comment: Any chance of a link so people can play with it?

Comment: if I go into the console (using Chrome) and type `$("img.gDisplay")` it returns null.

Comment: sorry should've clarified. The expanded image (after clicking) is .gDisplay

Comment: Thanks.  Well I'm not sure why, but it _isn't_ finding gDisplay in IE8.  My guess is that something during creation of that element is going wrong and the error message you are seeing is a consequence of it.  Try debugging step-by-step in IE8 and checking that everything is being created as it should be.

Comment: so it's not showing it even after clicking on one of the boxes. I don't know if you saw, but gDisplay is defined upon the images creation "var display = $('<img class="gDisplay" num="' + $(img).attr('num') + '" />')"